# How to filter out JSON keys that are empty(null?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, null

I am looping through set keys of a JSON file.  Sometimes these key's values will be empty(null? is null the proper word?).  because of this it creates an error in an later interaction.  I would like to remove these empty values from being sent to the `val[]`.

**Exampe JSON:**

```
post_a: "THis is key 1"
post_b: "this is key 2"
post_c: "this is key 3"
post_d: "" 
 // I want to filiter out post_d because it is empty
```

**Loop:**

```
 keys = ["post_a", "post_b", "post_c", "post_d"]; 
 val = [];
 $.each(keys, function(i, key) {
     val[i] = data[key];
     return val[i];
  });
```

Currently, after this loop finishs: `val.length = 4`  If this was to work as intended: `val.length = 3`

Comment: _"empty(null? is null the proper word?)"_ - No, an empty string and `null` are not the same thing. And your example "JSON" is not JSON at all. Also it doesn't make sense to have `return val[i];` in your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
keys = ["post_a", "post_b", "post_c", "post_d"]; 
 val = [];
 $.each(keys, function(i, key) {
     if(data[key]){
       val[i] = data[key];
       return val[i];
     }
  });
```

There is no null check in your code. It just adds everything all the time. Try the above

Comment: You can remove the `return val[i];` line too - in the context of a `$.each()` callback testing for non-empty strings it's not doing anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (data[key]) {
    // var is defined, do your code
}
```

Comment: What if `data[key]` has been given the value `false`? Then it is defined but won't work with your if test. (Yes, I know the OP only seems to be using strings, but still a more general solution wouldn't hurt.)

Comment: @nnnnnn not necessary but definably excellent way to make light of a bad question.

Comment: you cannot use `typeof` here because it returns object on `Null`

Comment: My objection was to the comment "var is defined" because that's not what the if condition is testing - more specifically, it will ignore properties defined with falsy values... I don't see what that has to do with `typeof`.